# What's the difference between "hallow", "sacred", "holy" and "saint"?

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

*Hallow, sacred, holy* and *saint* seem to resemble each other but are not identical. So what's the difference between them?

I have searched http://dictionary.babylon.com and spotted:

> **Hallow**:
>   sanctify, consecrate, bless, exalt, glorify
>
> **Sanctify**:
>   consecrate, make holy; make free from sin, purify; become holy
>
> **Saint**:
>   person canonized by the Christian Church for his holy qualities; extremely holy person, very righteous person
>
> **Sacred**:
>   holy, worthy of reverence; sanctified, consecrated; pertaining to religion
>
> **Holy**:
>   sacred, consecrated; divine; devoted to the service of God or religion; saintly, godly

So to *hallow* is to *make holy*, a *saint* is a *holy person*, but *holy* and *sacred* are circularly defined...

Comment: Popopo: How would others know, just from reading your question, that you've even bothered to look these up?  And what would prevent others from spending time copying dictionary definitions which you've already studied?  That's why @coleopterist is giving the very valid hint that you need to elaborate on this question. For a good example to work from, see [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79739/stack-vs-pile-vs-heap-of-paper).

Comment: @coleopterist Okay, no problem.

Comment: This question assumes there's a difference. Remember English is chock full of synonyms that have almost no definable difference other than the difference of the contexts where their use is most common. Oh, and Saint=noun, hallow=verb, Sacred,Holy=adjectives.  Core non-circular word behind all of these is that the moral perfection that pertains to a Deity is being referred to, either as Holy, or Sacred, with mean about the same thing.

Comment: @WarrenP It's certainly true that there are many words in English that have no discernable difference in meaning from another English word. But it's also true that there are many words that have similar meanings but with subtle shades of difference in meaning or different connotations. Dictionary definitions do not always make this clear. I think it's perfectly legitimate for someone to question whether in any particular case, the words mean exactly the same thing or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you note in your question, "holy" and "sacred" are adjectives, "hallow" and "sanctify" are verbs, and "saint" is a noun. To "hallow" is to "make holy" and to "sanctify" is to "make sacred". So there's little mystery about that difference.

The more interesting question is the difference between "holy" and "sacred". Every dictionary I checked called them synonyms and/or defined them in terms of each other, as you note. I think for everyday speech they should be regarded as synonymous. Of course you can't take dictionary definitions too literally: they often miss connotations, shades of meaning, and technical meanings.

I just did a quick search of a New King James Bible for the two words (using biblegateway.com) and I notice this: "holy" is consistently used to refer to things dedicated or set apart for God, like the "Holy Place" in the temple, the place where God spoke to Moses as "holy ground", Israel being set apart as a "holy nation", etc. It is used very often in many different contexts. The word "sacred" is almost always used in just two contexts: referring to meetings for a religious purpose as "sacred assemblies", and referring to the posts used in the worship of Baal and Asherah as "sacred pillars".

So I'm not sure what conclusions to draw. It appears that the Bible freely uses "sacred" to refer to things from other religions, but uses "holy" only to refer to Jewish and Christian things. My tentative conclusion -- and I will gladly yield here to someone with more solid evidence -- is that both words mean "dedicated or set apart for god or the Gods", but that "sacred" means something that people have dedicated to their god, while "holy" means something that God has set apart for himself.

Comment: +1. It looks like we've come to pretty much the same conclusion (but you've supplied somewhat more evidence).

Comment: +1, I suppose that the conclusions are right, but the principle you assume, in itself, is probably erroneous. By employing different premises, especially in etymological sense, I presume we could get some better results.

Comment: The contextual distinction that you've found between 'holy' and 'sacred' could be native to English, or it couldd have been an artifact of translation, the original language having a distinction and then that mapped arbitrarily to two synonymous English words.

Comment: @Carlo_R. what premise/principle was assumed that you think is erroneous?

Comment: @Mitch Jay assumed that the meaning of these two words can be figured out through the NKJB, but I'm sure the distinction, in etymological sense, should be searched outside the Christian things. I suppose we can understand this mistery by studing the ancient Germanics whose loved to know of these marvelous concepts.

Comment: @Mitch: That's a good thought. To test it, I've repeated the search that Jay describes, and looked at various hits from the Hebrew Bible. Indeed, in all cases of "holy" that I looked at, it represented the Hebrew adjective *kadosh* "holy" or noun *kodesh* "holiness" (the latter being used attributively: "___ of holiness" = "holy ___"). However, the cases of "sacred" were more variable; "sacred assembly/meeting" consistently represented *atsara*, "sacred pillar" consistently represented *matseva*, and -- most importantly IMHO -- in II Kings 12:8 "sacred thing" represented *kodesh* ("holiness").

Comment: @Mitch I considered checking what words were used in the original Hebrew, Aramaic, and Greek, but didn't because, (a) I was too lazy, and (b) that could give us clues to the meaning of the English words but would not be definitive. I see Ruakh got ambiguous results for "sacred" using that method. If this was a Bible study and we were debating the meaning of a Bible verse, recourse to the Hebrew would be valuable. But here we're asking about the English used to translate.

Comment: @Carlo_R. I don't think etymologies would resolve questions about this sort of fine shade of meaning. I could study the Latin and Germanic roots of the words "inter" and "net" for years and this would never lead me to the current definition of "Internet".

Comment: @trig Yeah, I got a chuckle when I posted mine and saw that seconds before I clicked the button, you had posted a very similar answer.

Comment: @Ruakh: holy < [Germanic heilig = holy cognate to heil/health, used to translate Latin santcus](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=holy), sacred < [Fr sacre < Lat sacrere cognate to sanctus.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sacred).

Comment: @Mitch: For the Hebrew Bible, the KJV was translated from the Hebrew text, not via the Vulgate.

Comment: An additional argument for your conclusion is that sacred is sometimes used to describe things that are not explicitly religious, as in "our Lives, our Fortunes, and our sacred Honor" or to refer to something that must not be questioned or changed.

Answer (score 8):

In my own usage, a *sacred* object or place is one that humans have deemed to be dedicated to their God(s), while a *holy* object or place is one that God has reserved for his use. In other words, you could well believe that the artefacts of another religion are not actually holy, but accept that they are nonetheless sacred.

In many religions, God himself/the Gods themselves are regarded as *holy*, not *sacred*.

I'm afraid I cannot distinguish *hallow* and *sanctify* so clearly, but I think there's a whisper of the same distinction: generally speaking, it's a priest who sanctifies something, and a God who hallows it. (The only occurrence of *hallow* I can think of recently is Yavanna hallowing certain items in *The Silmarillion*, which accords with this usage.)

Unlike the others, *saint* is a specifically Christian term, and its meanings differ between different branches of Christianity. In some definitions, all Christians are "saints". In others, a saint is a specifically virtuous, righteous, and holy person.

Comment: RE "saint": Specifically, Catholics use "saint" to refer to a person who is particularly meritorious and has been selected through a formal procedure as worthy of this title. Protestants use "saint" to mean any Christian. Whether this is a substantive disagreement or just two different definitions for the same word is a subject for a different forum.

Comment: @Jay. You could try it on Christianity SE if you like, but I don't think it would fly. I tend to say that such questions are not even meaningful.

Comment: I have read the use of "Saint" to refer to people in the Muslim religion, as well as of Sikh "Saints".  As the english word saint comes from the Latin sanctus, the original use is indeed a term specific to Christianity, but that is no longer the case.

Comment: @WarrenP. It looks confusing, so I've [asked a question](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/3034/156).

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have two Modern English words that mean almost exactly the same thing, it is probable that only one existed in Old English, while the other was imported from the Romance languages, there having been several such bulk imports in English's history.  This appears to be the situation with *holy* and *sacred*: the former is Old English, the latter comes from Latin *sacer* by way of French *sacre* and the oldest citation in the OED is 1380 (referring specifically to the Eucharist).

Whenever you have a question of English etymology, the canonical reference is the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/).  This is what it says about the etymology of *holy*; note the explicit comparison to *sanctus*, *sacer*.

> **holy**, *adj.* and *n.*
> **Etymology:**  Old English *hálig*, *-eg* (in inflection contracted to *hálg-*), also Northumbrian *hǽlig* (whence northern Middle English *hely*), Old Frisian *hêlech*, Old Saxon *hêlag*, *-eg* (Middle Dutch *heilech*, *-egh-*, Dutch *heilig*), Old High German *heilag* (Middle High German *heilec*, German *heilig*), Old Norse *heilagr* (Swedish *helig*, Danish *hellig*) < Old Germanic type **hailag-oz*, the sense of which is expressed in the Gothic of Ulfilas by *weihs* (but *hailag*, apparently ‘consecrated, dedicated’, is read on a Runic inscription generally held to be Gothic). A derivative of the adj. **hailo-*, Old English *hál*, free from injury, whole, hale, or of the derivative n. **hailoz-*, **hailiz-*, in Old High German *heil*, Old Norse *heill* health, happiness, good luck, in Old Norse also omen, auspice.
>
> The sense-development < *hailo-* is not clear, because the primitive pre-Christian meaning is uncertain, although it is with some probablity assumed to have been ‘inviolate, inviolable, that must be preserved *whole* or intact, that cannot be injured with impunity’, a sense preserved in Old Norse; hence the adj. would naturally be applied to the gods, and all things specially pertaining to them; and, with the introduction of Christianity, it would be a ready word to render Latin *sanctus*, *sacer*. But it might also start < *hail-* in the sense ‘health, good luck, well-being’, or be connected with the sense ‘good omen, auspice, augury’, as if ‘of good augury’: compare Old High German *heilisôn*, Old English *hálsian*, to HALSE v., augur, divine, exorcise, etc. The sense arrangement here is therefore merely provisional; we cannot in Old English get behind Christian senses in which *holy* is equated with Latin *sanctus*, *sacer*.